# calculate quantile for each group i dataframe and assign NA?

Tags: r

I made up this example to explain my question:

```
 df= structure(list(group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 10L, 10L
   ), .Label = c("Eve", "ba", "De", "De","Mi", "C", "O", "W", 
"as", "ras", "Cro", "ics"), class = "factor"), ds = c(8, 8, 
 1, 4, 4, 6), em = c(1, 3, 8,2, 7, 3)), row.names = c(74567L, 
74568L, 74570L, 74576L, 74577L, 74578L), class = "data.frame")
```

I need for each group to assign all values of em and ds to NA

```
 > quantile 90 = NA

 < quantile 10 = NA
```

Comment: Quantile of what? Quantile of `ds` or quantile of `em`?

Comment: of both variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do it for each group and each numeric variable using dplyr and `ifelse`.

Having only a couple of samples per group makes it difficult to interpret the whole concept of quantiles, so the result you get very much depends on how you define a quantile. The `type` parameter allows you to specify the definition you are using. R defaults to `type = 7`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
   group_by(group) %>% 
   mutate(ds = ifelse(ds > quantile(ds, .9) | ds < quantile(ds, .1), NA, ds),
          em = ifelse(em > quantile(em, .9) | em < quantile(em, .1), NA, em))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#> # Groups:   group [3]
#>   group    ds em   
#>   <fct> <dbl> <lgl>
#> 1 Eve       8 NA   
#> 2 Eve       8 NA   
#> 3 ba       NA NA   
#> 4 ba       NA NA   
#> 5 ras      NA NA   
#> 6 ras      NA NA
```

However, you can change this depending on your definition:

```
df %>% 
   group_by(group) %>% 
   mutate(ds = ifelse(ds > quantile(ds, .9, type = 1) | 
                      ds < quantile(ds, .1, type = 1), NA, ds),
          em = ifelse(em > quantile(em, .9, type = 1) |
                      em < quantile(em, .1, type = 1), NA, em))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#> # Groups:   group [3]
#>   group    ds    em
#>   <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Eve       8     1
#> 2 Eve       8     3
#> 3 ba        1     8
#> 4 ba        4     2
#> 5 ras       4     7
#> 6 ras       6     3
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>